# I am getting "syntax error near unexpected token `'$#''" in a simple Bash script

Tags: bash, syntax

I'm using [Debian 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_10_(Buster)) (Buster) and am getting an error in a simple Bash script. All it does is check to see if one parameter is passed in, and if it's a file, just echo out the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
if [ ( '$#' -eq 1 ) && ( -f "$1" ) ]; then
        echo "$1"
fi

exit 1
```

I get this error:

```
line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `'$#''
line 2: `if [ ( '$#' -eq 1 ) && ( -f "$1" ) ]; then'
```

I have tried every combination of quotes (", ', no quotes) around the `$#`, and I always get a variant of those error messages using the type of quotes I use. I can't figure out what it's looking for.

Comment: You may find https://shellcheck.net/ helpful

Comment: You don't actually need the `$# -eq 1` test. The `-f` test would be false if there was no argument. Also, you shouldn't `exit 1` if the script is successful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[` is a command, so the problem is really the way you're trying to use multiple conditions. You want this:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ -f "$1" ]; then
```

Answer (score 21):

There are two issues here. First, the simple `[` builtin can't contain `&&`. If you want to combine multiple conditions, you need multiple `[`:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ -f "$1" ]; then
```

Second, you can't use single quotes around the `$#` since that needs to be expanded. Your version, with `'$#' -eq 1` was comparing the *string* `$#` to the number 1.

The whole thing is much simpler if you use bash's `[[` keyword instead:

```
if [[  "$#" -eq 1  &&  -f "$1"  ]]; then
```

Answer (score 10):

Despite the other answers explaining how to fix the script, I wondered what the error was technically about. I think the only valid syntax where bash allows a word in a command to be an unquoted and unescaped `(` is when defining functions. So, bash saw `(` and immediately thought it had to be a definition for a function named `[`, but then you followed with `'$#'` and bash was only expecting `)`, so that's why you got that syntax error. If it wasn't meant to be a function definition, then who knows what it was meant to be. Anything else after `(` besides `)` would have raised the same syntax error:

```
$ echo ( foo )
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `foo'
```

If you remove what follows `(` that doesn't fit the syntax of a function definition, you get:

```
$ [ ( ) ( -f "$1" )
```

Which ends up defining the function `[`:

```
$ [
bash: -f: command not found
```

Comment: And the fact that it's an if-statement doesn't matter, you could still define a function within it. `if [ () { echo hello; }; then [; [; fi` prints `hello` twice.